# How to move to next month then next year in AutoFilter / Sort using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that has data added each month from another spreadsheet.

The other spreadsheet. I recorded a macro to do this month, but I don't know how to move the time forward.

I have criteria "2022" and Criteria "3", which presents a month.

How do I create the code to know that the next run should be "2022" and "4" and so on?

The month will have a max number of 12 and will eventually turn to "2023" and "1".

```vb
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="2022"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="3"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=AP", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Charges"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "=ST.2", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=ST.1"
    ActiveCell.Offset(6504, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(237, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the values 2022 and 3 in the last row of data ?

Comment: Technically yes. Once the columns are sorted the new data is pasted from another sheet to the last row.

Comment: And presumably the range `$A$1:$AH$24811` will also need to be changed to include the pasted data ?

Comment: Are they columns A to AH ?

Comment: Yes. New data would get pasted at the bottom. The files aren't like for like, meaning the column headers are not in the same order. The operation: Sort "primary spreadsheet" to latest fiscal year and period. Sort "new data spreadsheet" for latest fiscal year, period and type. Then new spreadsheet is copied into the primary spreadsheet into the appropriate columns. I think I can code the copy past. I just don't know how to do the filters. I appreciate your help and input.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the macro it will get the current month and year and put them in variables **vMonth** and **vYear**.

```
Sub runMacro()
    Dim vMonth As Long: vMonth = Month(Now())
    Dim vYear As Long: vYear = Year(Now())
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=vYear
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$24811").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=vMonth
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: But, it's not 2022 yet, and it's not month 3 yet either, right? So OP might be using fiscal month and year, not calendar month and year.

Comment: @BigBen you're right. I am looking at Fiscal Year 2022 which begins in September. The input data represents the prior month action, so data received in December would reflect activity for November 2022.

Answer (score 0):

This applies the filter using the values from the last row of data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub FilterData()

    Dim lastrow As Long, yr As Long, pd As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row
        yr = .Cells(lastrow, 11).Value2 ' col K
        pd = .Cells(lastrow, 12).Value2 ' col L
        With .Range("A1:AH" & lastrow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=yr
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=pd
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=AP", _
                Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Charges"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=ST.2", _
                Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=ST.1"
        End With
   End With
End Sub
```